# How to get the filename from an array of absolute paths of filenames

Tags: rm, arguments, parameter

I have a shell script that needs to delete the file names from the /tmp directory. The file names must be detected from a list of file names passed to my script.

```
./deletetmpfiles.sh /var/moht/test1.pdf  /var/shif/log/test4.pdf
```

Any number of files can be passed as arguments to the `deletetmpfiles.sh` script.

Considering the above example.

My script should delete `/tmp/test1.pdf` & `/tmp/test4.pdf`

Below is what I attempted.

```bsh
echo "Deleting the following files as they got printed: $@"

cd /home/system/bey.de/invoices/send4print

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "Deleting the following on the server: $@"
  echo "rm -f /tmp/$(basename $@)"
  rm -f /tmp/$(basename $@)
fi
```

But it deletes only the first file from /tmp i.e /tmp/test1.pdf and misses deleting the remaining files.

Can you please suggest?

Comment: `basename` doesn't deal with multiple files.

Answer (score 1):

`basename` doesn't deal with multiple files:

> NAME
>
> ```
> basename - strip directory and suffix from filenames
> ```
>
> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
>   basename NAME [SUFFIX]    basename OPTION...NAME...
> ```

Unless the `-a` option is used (GNU  Coreutils):

> ```
> -a, --multiple
>    support multiple arguments and treat each as a NAME
> ```

But it would break if the filenames have newlines.

And will fail in your command, since `basename -a` will return the arguments with new lines

```bsh
basename "$@"
foo.pdf
bar.pdf
```

Which breaks the `rm` command since the arguments passes are separated by new lines.

This code apparently solves the problem

```bsh
rm $(echo "$(basename -a "$@")")
```

but I'm not so sure of its validity.

---

Yo can then loop over the arguments:

```bsh
for i in "$@"; do 
  echo "rm -f /tmp/$(basename "$i")"
  rm -f "/tmp/$(basename "$i")"
done
```

---

To deal with names with spaces, they must be properly escaped when passed to the script:

```bsh
$ script.sh "foo bar.pdf"
```

Or

```bsh
$ script.sh foo\ bar.pdf
```

Comment: oops. :) But yeah, correctly quoted, it should be fine with whitespace.

Comment: GNU coreutils `basename` supports multiple arguments with `-a` (and `-z` for NUL-terminated output), but that doesn't make the `rm` easier...

Comment: `basename -a` could be coerced to use, but it would break if the filenames have newlines. And `-z` would be pretty much impossible to use in a script. It might have been better if they'd not even implemented things like that.

Comment: @ilkkachu If you want you can check my updated answer.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity, well, in that rm-echo-basename command, the step with `echo` adds the word splitting that adding quotes around `"$(basename -a "$@")"` inhibits. So you could just do `rm $(basename -a "$@")` instead. But that breaks on regular spaces too (so you need to change `IFS`), and uses the names as globs (so you need to disable that), which is pretty much why I didn't want to go there in the first place. :) It's better to do it with a loop (which we already have here!), that way the filenames are separate from the go, and stay separate for the whole time.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest getting a solid basic knowledge before proceeding to more complicated stuff.

As usually there are more ways to accomplish given task.

A fundamental question of your example is: "What exactly `$@` stands for?"

Answer might be: "all the command line arguments as separate, individual strings." (Robbins & Beebe: Classic Shell Scripting)

If you want to process all the individual members of this argument, you would need a cycle.

Variant 1:

```bsh
for file in "$@" ; do
  echo "Deleting the following on the server: $file"
  file=$(basename $file)
  echo "rm -f /tmp/$file"
  rm -f /tmp/$file
done
```

Variant 2:

```bsh
until [ $# = 0 ]; do
  echo "Deleting the following on the server: $file"
  file=$(basename $file)
  echo "rm -f /tmp/$file"
  rm -f /tmp/$file
  shift
done
```

In variant 2 `shift` makes the argument list shorter every iteration.